# rsync'ed outputs are always marked as outdated

Tags: remote-server, targets-r-package

Using {targets} to manage a workflow, which is great.

We don't have a proper cluster setup, but I have access to remote machines with much better specs than my laptop, so I can use git to keep the plan in sync locally and remotely.

When I want to work with something locally, I use `rsync` to move the files over.

```
rsync -avxP -e "ssh -p ..." remote:path/to/_targets .
```

When I query the remote cache with `tar_network`, I see that a bunch of my targets are "uptodate".

When I query the local cache after the `rsync` above, those same targets are "outdated".

I'm wondering if there is either better calls to `rsync` or certain arguments to `tar_network()`, or if this is a bug and the targets *should* stay as "uptodate" after an `rsync` like this?

Comment: Have you tried looking on the discussions page of targets https://github.com/ropensci/targets/discussions/ ? I [asked something similar](https://github.com/ropensci/targets/discussions/649#discussioncomment-1392471), perhaps it helps you

Comment: Yeah, that is definitely similar. But I feel like there should be {targets} or rsync options that lets the relevant information be captured across machines.

Comment: You can comment on the question or develop your own (automated) solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I figured this out.

It was because I was being foolish about what was a target in this case. To make sure that a package dependency was being captured, I was using something that grabbed the entire `DESCRIPTION` of the package (`packageDescription()` I think). The problem with that is, is that when you install the package using `remotes::install_github()`, is that it adds some more information to the `DESCRIPTION` upon installation (`packaged` and `built` fields), and that information differed between the installation on my local machine and the installation on the remote machine.

What I really wanted was just the `GithubSHA1` bit from the `packageDescription()`, to verify that I was using the same package at the same commit from my GitHub repo. Once I switched to using that instead of the entire `DESCRIPTION`, then `targets` had no issues with the meta information and things would stay current when `rsync`'ing them between machines.